# Append Input By Button Click using React

Tags: reactjs, input, react-forms

[image]

I want to do something like that. Clicking the button will spawn input element. I checked some codes but all codes spawn like

**food category food category food name food name**

**it should be order by clicked which button**. How should I update my code?

```
const foodCategoryInput = () => {

}



function NewMenu() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Create New Menu</h1>
            <button onClick={foodCategoryInput}>Add Food Category</button>
            <button>Add Food Name</button>
            <div id='menuItems'>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Food Category'></input>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Food Name'></input>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Food Name'></input>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Food Name'></input>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Food Category'></input>




            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, or the interface. You have two Food Category fields separated by three Food Name fields. Are you saying you got that by clicking on "Add Food Category", "Add Food Name" three times, and then "Add Food Category"?

Comment: lets say I clicked 3 times foodCategory, 2 times FoodName button.

fields should be like

fc fc fc fn fn

If I click 1 time FN 2 times FC 1 time should be like

FN FC FC FN

Comment: Why would there be two FC in your second example? You only clicked once. Also, those are not in the order you clicked... In any case, add items (strings, objects, whatever you think you need) to an array, then [use `map` to map them to `input`s](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: myfault...  I written just 1 time. it was 1 time fc. could you write the psuedo code for me if its possible

Answer (score 0):

As with most questions regarding MVC-style libraries and frameworks, if you are asking about how to do it in the DOM, you've already lost the thread.

The key, in these types of libraries, is to separate the model from the presentation. You have a model: you want to get Food Categories and Food Names in a specific order. You just need to make that into code:

```js
// Example stateless functional component
const SFC = props => ( <div><input type="text" placeholder={(props.type === 'name' ? 'Food Name' : 'Food Category')} data-id={props.id} value={props.value} onChange={props.change} /></div>
);

// Example class component
class Thingy extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const foods = [{
          key: 1,
          type: 'name',
          value: ''
        }, {
          key: 2,
          type: 'category',
          value: ''
        }];
        const {
          title
        } = this.props;
        console.log("rendered");
        return ( <div>
            <div>{title}</div> 
            {
              foods.map(food => ( 
                <SFC type={food.type}
                     key={food.key}
                     id={food.key}
                     value={food.value}
                     change={(e) => {
                      console.log(e.target.value);
                     }
                   } />
                )
              )
            }
          </div>);
       }
    }

    // Render it
    ReactDOM.render(<Thingy title="I'm the thingy" />,
                    document.getElementById("root")
                   );
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

This is the general idea. I leave getting the updating of the elements and storing back into the array for you. There are plenty of tutorials online about that.